# It is possible to change loss in Tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection-api

i want to change loss of object detection for ones of object detection (such as SSD) ,

Q1 : i want to know where do i modify the loss function for SSD ,

Q2 : is it possible to fine-tune ssd_mobilenet on my dataset with my define loss ? is it good or must be train ssd_mobile from scratch with my loss function ?

Answer (score 0):

Q1:
If you are using the [object detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) then a config is used to define the network and the loss, such as these:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs

Looking at a basic [ssd mobilenet config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config) you should see the losses it is using, including a classification loss and localization loss.  You can look at other configs to see other loss options, or look at the source code for the full list of options or even modify the source code to add your own loss.

Q2:
It is certainly possible, but you will need to dig into the internals of how the object detection api works, modify it to add your loss function and train on your dataset.  It will be more work than you might expect.  Knowing nothing about your dataset or metric, I expect your fine-tuned result will converge more quickly than a from scratch result and give comparable results.

Comment: Thank you！Q1:Just want to add new loss, for example add RepGT loss https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07752.pdf in ssdlite_mobilenet_v2 . However,I am not familiar with TensorFlow debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the loss function in the configuration file like line 198 in the link - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config , when you do this the performance will be drastically reduced may if you retrain the network performance may improve.

If you can elaborate on the goal more clearly, it would be helpful to suggest the solution.

Comment: Thank you！Q1:Just want to add new loss, for example add RepGT loss https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07752.pdf in ssdlite_mobilenet_v2/ssdlite_mobilenet_v3.However,I am not familiar with TensorFlow debug mode.